# What are int32_t , uint16_t .... in stdint.h

Tags: c, stdint

What does int32_t and uint16_t refer to ?

And what are they : macros , data types ...

And where we can use them ?

Comment: Did you look to /usr/include/stdint.h ? It's typedefs.

Comment: Use when you need to explicitly an integer that can be held.

Comment: I'm surprised you weren't able to find any information about this on the Internet already.

Comment: If they exist, they are typedefs for integer types with exactly the corresponding number of bits and two's complement representation.

Comment: I already looked in many website but i still a beginner i didn't understand exactly what they trying to say

Comment: If you couldn't understand the plethora of resources online you likely won't get an answer here that you can comprehend. I suggest you go back and take an introductory programming class.

Comment: Interestingly, searching for `uint16_t` on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US shows several stackoverflow answers.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're having some basic knowledge gaps.
I recommend to do a tutorial first, to get a fundamental knowledge about programming in c.

For example one of those:

[Wikibooks: C Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming)

[Digital Ocean: Learn-C](http://www.learn-c.org/)

And also try to get handy with data types.

ahoi!